# SNMP set-request return value

Tags: php, snmp

I'm trying to use SNMP to extract WAN IP address information from Huawei ONT.

Example:

First make a set request (pay attention to the OIDs last index).
1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.145.1.1.1.3.1.3.4194305024.0.65535

In the command line the set request returns the data sent but with another index. If I repeat the set command the index is increased by 1.

1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.145.1.1.1.3.1.3.4194305024.0.**248**

Using this OID I can get the IP address but PHP SNMP extension only returns boolean from set command. Someone has any tip ?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used the snmpset to set the values as described above and got the new OID then I made a snmpget and got the data. The point is how to get the package return data (with the new OID) in PHP?

Comment: To that effect, I think some PHP code you tried would be useful. Please annotate the code with what you expect at certain points, and what the actual behaviour is :)

Comment: Well I didn't tried any PHP code because the PHP doc says SNMP class set method returns only boolean. The same happens with the procedural form. So I wrote this bash script to test the process only. I know I can use shell_exe but I would like to avoid using it. Maybe is there any way to extend the PHP class or something more elegant. :)
I come here after a day digging it in the internet.

Comment: Well, `snmpget` doesn't return a boolean, for instance: http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php

Comment: Yes I know, I'm talking about the snmpset or SNMP::set method.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, without seeing the actual code/command used to perform your set request, it sounds as if the agent is misbehaving. The agent should always send back the *exact same varbinds* in the response as were specified in the set request. Therefore, there's no significantly useful reason for PHP's SNMP::set method to return them. If you are doing a set on OID X and the agent responds with with an OID other than X, then the agent is broken.